# Editing mt2s files

Tags: vlc, shotwell, editing, avidemux

I'm trying to find alternative program(s) for importing/editing/converting video files from my Sony camcorder. Type of files is - mt2s. Camcorder came with a program called Sony Picture Browser (PMB), which works only in windows. I can not install it with wine, so I searched for alternatives in ubuntu:

VLC - can open files, edit them (brightness, contrast, sharpen,...) - but I'm having trouble with basic editing like cutting and joining files - I cut with option view/advanced controls - and then I can record desired part of file...problem is, that you have to wait all the time it records file...for joining files I haven't found right option

Avidemux - when I try to open mt2s file I get error message "This looks like mpeg. Do you want to index it?"...if I say no, the file doesn't open, if I say yes, there is another message "If the file is using B-frames as reference it can lead to a crash or stuttering..." and it ofers me "safe mode"...if I choose it video is sloow, if I don't, it offer me option Tool/rebuild frame and if I use it, then video is ok...but that is way too complicated (can I get mt2s files to open without that error messages?)

Shotwell - it opens files, but there is no option of cutting/joining files

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be terribly wrong, but I guess the MTS container is the problem.

You might try to convert the videos to *.mp4 using

```
avconv -i whatever.mt2s goodstuff.mp4
```

Comment: That would be an option, but I like to check my videos first and delete some of them + cut shorter some other...that way I get rid of unneeded data...with direct convertion I would also have to convert that unneeded material (time consuming)

Comment: @mo Does OpenShot import these files? It's just a guess, I don't own a Sony camcorder.

Comment: Yes it does...I haven't checked that program before...looks good at first sight...i'll try it

Comment: That's what I have been looking for...thank you Klaus!